# highlight text synced with jw player

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to highlight blocks of text according to a block of text synced with a video

So far I have

```
(function($){


    $.fn.playerConnect = function(player){


        var transcriptElements = this;


        player.onTime(function(evt){

      var time =  ''; 

         console.log(time);       
}; 


                 $.each(transcriptElements, function(){
                   var start = $(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-start");
                   var end = $(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-start") + $(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-dur");
                   var startNum = parseFloat(start);
                   var endNum = parseFloat(end);
                   console.log(startNum);
                   if (time >= startNum && time <= endNum){
                        $(transcriptElements[i]).addClass("hilite");
                   } else {
                        $(transcriptElements[i]).removeClass("hilite");
                   } 
                });

        });


        return this.click(function(evt){

       })
   };

})(jQuery);
```

And the html I am trying to pull from to hilite is set into different spans is here.  I need to take each different span which corresponds with a different time in the video, and hilite the text.

```
<div id="playerDiv">Video Will Appear Here</div>
      <div id="transcript"> <span class="words" data-start="10.099" data-dur="7"></span>
        <span class="words" data-start="17.869" data-dur="3.82">Hey this is
          Dwayne Johnson. While playing astronaut Chuck Baker in the film Planet</span>
        <span class="words" data-start="21.689" data-dur="0.701">51</span> <span
          class="words" data-start="22.39" data-dur="3.56">I gained a lot of
          respect for our nation's space program. NASA makes new</span> <span class="words"
          data-start="25.95" data-dur="1.35">discoveries about our universe</span>
        <span class="words" data-start="27.3" data-dur="4.11">every day but one
          of the coolest things about nasa is the technologies that</span> <span
          class="words" data-start="31.41" data-dur="1.55">it creates for
          exploring space</span> <span class="words" data-start="32.96" data-dur="3.739">are
          also improving life here on earth. NASA technologies can be found</span>
        <span class="words" data-start="36.699" data-dur="0.621">everywhere</span>
        <span class="words" data-start="37.32" data-dur="3.71">from the soles of
          the shoes to the freeze dried fruit in your cereal. These</span> <span
          class="words" data-start="41.03" data-dur="1.58">technologies, called
          spinoffs,</span> <span class="words" data-start="42.61" data-dur="4.36">help
          doctors heal patients with heart problems, scientists track rare
          animals, and</span> <span class="words" data-start="46.97" data-dur="2.409">firefighters
          and police officers and soldiers</span> <span class="words" data-start="49.379"
          data-dur="4.45">stay safe on the job. Space technology has even helped
          Olympic swimmers win</span> <span class="words" data-start="53.829" data-dur="0.711">gold
          medals.</span> <span class="words" data-start="54.54" data-dur="3.63">All
          of these the spinoffs began as innovations for nasa missions</span> <span
          class="words" data-start="58.17" data-dur="3.86">like the space
          shuttle, the Hubble Space Telescope, and the International Space</span>
        <span class="words" data-start="62.03" data-dur="3.18">Station. You
          don't have to be an astronaut to trace</span> <span class="words" data-start="65.21"
          data-dur="3.47">space back to where you live. Visit nasa.gov</span> <span
          class="words" data-start="68.68" data-dur="3.549">to learn more about
          how nasa technologies play a role in your life.</span> <span class="words"
          data-start="72.229" data-dur="3.331">After all, there's no space like
          home</span> </div>
```

Comment: You provided some code, but haven't explained what is or isn't working. If this code only runs once it will only evaluate the time when it is run. Show more code and provide a better explanation. Also need to know if `transcriptElements[i]` is a valid jQuery selector

Comment: Sorry this is what else I had

Comment: I apologize I am honestly still new at programming and really need some help, but I edited the question to update my code

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .hilite {
      background-color: YELLOW;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var transcriptElements = $("span");
    var i = 0;
    var time = 18;
        $.each(transcriptElements, function(){
               var start = $(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-start");
               var end = new Number($(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-start")) + new         Number($(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-dur"));
               var startNum = parseFloat(start);
               var endNum = parseFloat(end);
               if (time >= startNum && time <= endNum){
                    $(transcriptElements[i]).addClass("hilite");
               } else {
                    $(transcriptElements[i]).removeClass("hilite");
               } 
               i++;
            });


            });
    </script>
```